# Why would this PCB design cause a short?

Tags: pcb, short-circuit, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

Yesterday, I designed my first ever PCB. It's meant to take data from several sensors and pass the data to a Raspberry Pi, which will in turn actuate pumps to control nutrient concentrations in a hydroponic system.

When I took this PCB to my professor, he said it would cause a short because of the way the MCP3008 was connected using two layers. He gave me an explanation that I didn't really understand. Can someone clear this up for me?

[image: Here is a screenshot I took within Fritzing.]

[Link to the Fritzing fzz file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ZrInxhGq75TYyru2lqztp8HxBq7bLmp/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Would you also add the schematic please ? makes it easier to see what is going on

Comment: So what was the actual explanation?  Was it related to trace to pad clearances?  Does your PCB software have a DRC (Design Rule Check) enabled?

Comment: @Nedd He said that since the IC I'm using is a DIP, it would cause a short. Because the copper traces aren't isolated and the IC pins are conductive.

I did test with DRC and I didn't get any errors.

Comment: There are some traces that run pretty close to other pads, like the trace from pin 1 goes very close to pin 2. If the PCB is done without solder mask, you could easily create a solder bridge from the pin to that trace. Might have been what he meant. But with solder mask, it would probably work. Although I personally would move those traces for some better clearance since there is space available so why not.

Comment: Wouldn't your professor be in the best position to clarify their own explanation? Did you tell them you didn't understand? It's their job to teach you.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny That makes sense, I'll try to make more space.

Comment: those tolerances seem fine for most fabs these days. maybe the cheapest or oldest fabs couldn't handle them. it's also a bit close for hand-rolled boards, unless you have a lot of practice with registration.

Comment: @TypeIA He spent 30 min trying to explain what he was trying to say, I think its just because of the disconnect in knowledge and vocabulary. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Unless you can tell us what would make a short, I have hard time seeing what would make a short here. Please note professors are also humans and make mistakes by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted in other comments, some of the traces are fairly close to other IC pads. The better practice for connecting traces to IC pads is to allow for the best clearance when it is practical. For example on the MCP3008 chip, the trace connected to pin 3 initially comes horizontally straight away from the pad before the diagonal turn, this gives a good maximum clearance. Now looking at the connection of pin 1 which hits the pad at center directly from the diagonal trace, the trace to pad clearance is much less (to pin 2). If there are slight variations in PCB alignment there is a higher chance of that trace and the nearby pad shorting together. Also if solder mask is not ideal (or is offset a slight amount, or not included at all) there is a chance that during the soldering operation a short could develop. You have a few other pad connections with this potential issue.

Comment: I made some changes, here's the edited design.

[Link to exported PDF](https://gofile.io/d/VRXwKi)

Comment: Yes, improved.  Perhaps the traces to pins 9 and 14 could use similar improvement.  Moving the via out from under the chip would allow pin 9 to have a better connection.

Comment: You have the same case in P9-P10 and P12-P13. Would you solder components by hand?

Comment: @Nedd I took your advice and fixed those too. I think the traces come too close to pins 9-11 though. Will that be a problem?

[Link to new PDF](https://gofile.io/d/8K171M)

Comment: @Juanma I have fixed those issues I think. Yes, I will be soldering these by hand.

Comment: @Extr3mis, Looking better again.  It would also be good to straighten out some of the traces after the last few modifications.  No reason to have traces longer than needed, or with excessive twists and turns. There are a handful of other possible improvements that could be made on your board, though they may not score you much in the way of a better project grade. Plus you might need to explain to your professor all the reasons behind the improvements.

Comment: @Nedd I understand. Thanks so much for your guidance!

Comment: Glad I could help out.  If satisfied with the answer(s) you could also tick the check mark at the top left of my answer.

Comment: The pcb is simply connecting the points but you have neglected where current is flowing and the voltage drop across your skinny tracks. Try using a ground fill and pay more attention to component placement to make the tracks easier.